# when Wiener amalgam space is a subset of Lebesgue space?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $X=\mathcal{F}L^{p}=\{f\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb R):\hat{f}\in L^{p}(\mathbb R)\},$ and $\|f\|_{X}= \|\hat{f}\|_{L^{p}}.$

In the definition of [Wiener amalgam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_amalgam_space) spaces $W(X, L^p)$, I am taking $X=\mathcal{F}L^{p}.$
(I am just  trying to understand the spaces)

My questions

1. Can we expect $W(\mathcal{F}L^{2}, L^{1}) \subset L^{1}$?
2. Can we expect $W(\mathcal{F}L^{1}, L^{2}) \subset L^{1}$?